# Parse RSS/Atom feeds with PHP's HTML DomDocument

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument, atom-feed

How to find the values for namespace content:encoded and dc:creator with the following code
Unfortunately I cannot use simplepie or magpierss or even simplexml.
I know I've to use $doc->getElementsByTagName, but cannot figure out where?

<?php    
function rss_to_array($tags, $array, $url) {

  $doc = new DOMdocument();
  @$doc->load($url);
  $rss_array = array();
  foreach($tags as $tag) {
    if ($doc->getElementsByTagName($tag)) {
      foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName($tag) AS $node) {
        $items = array();
        foreach($array AS $key => $values) {
          $items[$key] = array();
          foreach($values as $value) {
            if ($itemsCheck = $node->getElementsByTagName($value)) {
              for( $j=0 ;  $j < $itemsCheck->length; $j++ ) {
                if (($attribute = $itemsCheck->item($j)->nodeValue) != "") {
                  $items[$key][] = $attribute;
                } else if ($attribute = $itemsCheck->item($j)->getAttribute('term')) {
                  $items[$key][] = $attribute;
                } else if ($itemsCheck->item($j)->getAttribute('rel') == 'alternate') {
                  $items[$key][] = $itemsCheck->item($j)->getAttribute('href');
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        array_push($rss_array, $items);
      }
    }
  }
  return $rss_array;
}

$rss_item_tags = array('item', 'entry');
$rss_tags = array(
  'title' => array('title'),
  'description' => array('description', 'content', 'summary'),
  'link' => array('link', 'feedburner'),
  'category' => array('category')
);

$rssfeed = rss_to_array($rss_item_tags, $rss_tags, $url);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($rssfeed);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
?>

Comment: Can you update with your exact xml .... that would before helpful

Answer (score 1):

for RSS feeds, try using simplexml_load_file.  It creates an object out of the XML and, as all RSS feeds are the same, then you can do something like:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file(your_rss_url_here);

for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++){
// this is assuming there are 10 pieces of content for each RSS you're loading

    $link = $feed->channel->item[$i]->link;
    // do each for pubdate, author, description, title, etc.
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php